# ListBox multi thread

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a problem I'm trying to solve.
I have a application that reads a folder which has `.mp3` file in it.
I want to populate  the `ListView` with both the file name and the durations using **multi thread** as it takes too long if I do it in a single thread.

I can not seem to get this fast as hard as I try
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public arr(2) As String
Public itm As ListViewItem
Dim T1, t2 As Thread

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    T1 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.t1worker)
    T1.Start()
    t2 = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf t2worker)
    t2.Start()
 End Sub     

Public Sub t1worker()
    For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("f:\mvideo", "*.*")
        arr(0) = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)         
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub t2worker()
    Dim Duration As String
    Dim w As New WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer       
    For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("f:\mvideo", "*.*")
        If AllowedExtension.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower)  
            Dim m As WMPLib.IWMPMedia = w.newMedia(file)
            Duration = m.durationString
            arr(1) = Duration
        End If

        arr(1) = Duration
        itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
        trackinfo.Items.Add(itm)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Define "fast"  how fast do you need it?   I see other problems, t1 and t2 workers are asynchronously modifying "arr".  When you call New ListViewItem(arr), arr(0) may not be the filename which corresponds to the duration in arr(2).

Comment: Yes, it would be handy to know what 'too long' is? How many files? A few things I want to mention/ask. There's no need to do it twice, get the file and duration in the same routine/loop. What is `AllowedExtension` (a property array of extensions?). The second `arr(1) = Duration` is not needed and could cause an exception if the previous `if end if` is false because it could have no value. Lastly, your trackinfo (listview?) is on a different thread so a cross-thread exception will be raised so I'm not sure how you even got that to work without a delegate. I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Firstly, your title says `ListBox` but then your question indicat4es `ListView`. Mistakes like that may cause confusion so please be accurate in what you post.

Comment: Secondly, it's clear that you haven't bothered to read the documentation because, if you had, you'd know that you are supposed to populate an array or collection with all the `ListViewItems` and then add then to the `ListView` with a single call to `AddRange`. The way you're doing it, the control gets repainted every time you add an item and that's what makes it slow.  That's appart from the fact that you should not be populating the control in a secondary thread.

Comment: Something on the inner operation: instantiating a new `WindowsMediaPlayer` for each file, to just read a track length, is probably a bit too much. You could substitute everything with `BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate()` in a `Task` using `.BeginInvoke()`. To list the files in a directory and get extended informations on the Audio files, you could use the Shell COM library (`Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation`). Its `Folder.Items()` collection can be iterated. For each `FolderItem2` object, the `ExtendedProperty()` method returns all those details: "Author", "Genre", "Album", "Duration" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the threads And Try this just For grins.
I assume you listview is called trackinfo.
Comments and explanations in line.

```
Private Sub FillListView()
    'Using a List(Of T) because the number of items is indeterminate.
    Dim lstMP3 As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("f:\mvideo", "*.*")
        Dim liMP3 As New ListViewItem
        liMP3.Text = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
        'You probably need to send the full path to the function
        liMP3.SubItems.Add(GetDuration("Path & fileName"))
        lstMP3.Add(liMP3)
    Next
    'The .BeginUpdat /.EndUpdate prevents the listview from repainting of each
    'line addition greatly speeding up the process
    trackinfo.BeginUpdate
    trackinfo.Items.AddRange(lstMP3.ToArray)
    trackinfor.EndUpdate
End Sub
Private Function GetDuration(fileName As String) As String
    'Not at all sure how this works so you may have to adjust
    If AllowedExtension.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower) Then
        Dim m As WMPLib.IWMPMedia = w.newMedia(fileName)
        Duration = m.durationString
    End If
    Return Duration
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a database. Loaded the file name and duration into a database. Then populated the list from the database.